# Copy files with specific text at the end of their (file) names from one folder to other folder

Tags: python

I have 23000 files in one folder and want to copy files with their names ending with some specific text to other folder using python. I used the following code, though it runs successfully but it doesn't copy the file in the destination folder.

```
import os
import shutil
path = "D:/Snow_new/test"
outpath = "D:/Snow_new/testout"
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.endswith("clip_2"):
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(path, f), outpath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to copy files to a single filename again and again, so to fix it you will have to add the filename with outpath for every file

```py
import os
import shutil
path = "D:/Snow_new/test"
outpath = "D:/Snow_new/testout"

if not os.path.isdir(outpath):
    os.mkdir(outpath)
else:
    shutil.rmtree(outpath)
    os.mkdir(outpath)

for f in os.listdir(path):
    f2, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if f2.endswith("clip_2"):
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(path, f), os.path.join(outpath, f))
```

before running the above code make sure that you remove `D:/Snow_new/testout` completly

Comment: still nothing in the destination folder

Comment: please try again

Comment: Again nothing in the destination folder.  File names in the input folder are like "2000-03-05_clip_2.tif"

Comment: you must have told that filenames had extensions. retry the edited code please

Comment: Extremely Sorry, as I am new to python and just started learning how things work...Thank you so much it worked..